# Tkinter PhotoImage in a class won't show

Tags: python, tkinter, photoimage

I have a button that shows a new frame with a picture label in it. The label and image are exactly as they are in all the tutorials but the picture doesn't show. It is a .gif. What am I doing wrong?
Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Main(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.f1=Frame(root)
        self.f1.grid()
        b1=Button(f1, command=self.photo, text="Picture")
        b1.grid()

    def photo(self):
        self.f1.destroy()
        self.f2=Frame(root)
        self.f2.grid()
        self.img1=PhotoImage("CO2_Levels.gif")
        self.l3=Label(self.f2, image=self.img1)
        self.l3.image=self.img1
        self.l3.grid()

root=Tk()
app=Main(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default first argument is name for the image. If you are giving it a file path you need to specify `file=` in front of the path so that PhotoImage knows it's the path to the file rather than the name of the image.

```
self.img1=PhotoImage(file="CO2_Levels.gif")
```

Comment: @JonahFleming: if it says "file not found", it is a certainty that it can't find the file. You must be making a bad assumption on where you think it's looking, or what the actual name is. You can trust the error messages to be telling you the truth. Are you aware it doesn't look in the folder with the script? It looks in the furrent working directory.

Comment: Okay, thanks so how would I tell it to look in the directory that it is in without saying the path because I might need to move the file?

Comment: P.S are you going for moderator cause' I think you should.

Comment: @JonahFleming: no, not interested in being a moderator. I'd rather write answers than moderate them. Thanks for the kind words.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question. But if anyone run into the same problem, this is because the image gets garbage collected when you return from the function. To avoid this you should keep a reference to the image object. your photo method,

```
def photo(self):
    self.f1.destroy()
    self.f2=Frame(root)
    self.f2.grid()
    self.img1=PhotoImage("CO2_Levels.gif")
    self.l3=Label(self.f2, image=self.img1)
    self.l3.image = self.img1 # Reference to the image object  
    self.l3.image=self.img1
    self.l3.grid()
```

Source : http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm